# Applying a template file (dot) to a word document without office installed on the server

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ms-office

I am trying to apply a template file (dot) to a word document (doc) on a server where office is not  installed. I tried NPOI, but their libraries (XWPFDocument) support only docx and dotx formats. The library HWPFDocument that supports 97-2003 formats (doc and dot) is apparently going to available, but as of now available only as a scratchpad option.

Is there a way of doing the job at hand without installing office on the server?

I am working with .net 4.0 and coding in VB.Net.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

Comment: Aspose is a paid service and I am looking to see if this can be done without doing so.

Comment: Tried Aspose as well, I was able to generate doc files but the macros in the dot file aren't executed in the new document. They get copied over to the newly created file from the template but don't get executed. Apparently, according to other posts I read, executing a macro without interops is tough if not impossible. Is that right?